# Will tomcat creates a new session for every forward to a jsp page

Tags: struts

I want my web application to contain only one session created at login. But my server is creating a separate session for every request to a jsp page. How can I configure to have only one session in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If either a sessionId is supplied with every link the user clicks is submitted

or

cookies are used

the server can associate the request with a particular user. Otherwise a new session will be created.

EDIT:

for adding links to your URLs in case you dont have cookies ... there are some ways to do this. Either set the sessionId manually

```
<a href="home.jsp;sessionId=<%=request.getSession().getId()%>">link</a>
```

or use the struts-taglibs to that for you https://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#link

> Renders an HTML  element as an anchor definition (if "linkName" is specified) or as a hyperlink to the specified URL. URL rewriting will be applied automatically, to maintain session state in the absence of cookies. The content displayed for this hyperlink will be taken from the body of this tag.

The taglib then rewrites the link for you. It should look like this (not tested):

```
<html:link page="/linkoutput.jsp">Link</html:link>
```